# How to get the Selected Value by a JComboBox in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a JTable with a JComboBox CellEditor column. That works fine.
However, when I attempt to retrieve the selected value by the combo box, I am only getting the value that the mouse has selected in a specific row. I can't seem to get the selected value on a per row basis. 
here is my code:

```
  addressList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for(int currentRow = 0; currentRow < editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getRowCount(); currentRow++)
    {

            //ADDRESS
    offenderAddress = new MyAddress();


    DefaultCellEditor ownerEditor = (DefaultCellEditor) editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getCellEditor(currentRow, 1);       
    JComboBox ownerCb =(JComboBox) ownerEditor.getComponent();
    ListItem selectedItem =(ListItem) ownerCb.getSelectedItem();  //HERE IS WHERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM.I AM NOT GETTING THE VALUE FOR THE SPECIFIC ROW

    offenderAddress.setOwnerCode(selectedItem.getID());

    offenderAddress.setLine1(
            editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getModel().getValueAt(currentRow, 2).toString() 
            );

    offenderAddress.setLine2(
            editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getModel().getValueAt(currentRow, 3).toString() );

    offenderAddress.setCity(
            editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getModel().getValueAt(currentRow, 4).toString() );
    offenderAddress.setProvince(
            editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getModel().getValueAt(currentRow, 5).toString() );
    offenderAddress.setPostalZone(
            editAddressFrm.getAddressTable().getModel().getValueAt(currentRow, 6).toString() );
    }
```

Comment: So you want to get all the `row` values from the `row` you have selected in your `JTable`?

Comment: No. After the user has edited all the table fields, I want to save the fields to an address Object that I created. The problem is I am not getting  the selected Value of the JCombobox in the row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comboBox is only used to edit the cell. It does not contain the data for the cell.

You need to get the data from the table which is done by using:

```
table.getValueAt(...);
```

or

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(...);
```

depending on your exact requirement

If you are still editing the cell then the data may not be saved to the model yet. To solve this problem see: [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/).